# Run program with arguments

Tags: c#, process, arguments

how it works without C#:

1. Win + R
2. Type in this:

"C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.1.4\deploy\League of Legends.exe" "8394" "LoLLauncher.exe" "" "spectator 95.172.65.26:8088 If4hH4/27YhyycyAsxthGMnjzXaIgu7F 1249300997 EUW1"

As you can see, there are some arguments given to the process. I tried this:

```
string path = @"C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.1.4\deploy\League of Legends.exe";

string arguments =  @"""8394"" ""LoLLauncher.exe"" """" ""spectator 95.172.65.26:8088 " + firstgameinformation.Trim() + @" EUW1""";

Process.Start(path,arguments);
```

But the program isn't working the same way, it just crashes. There must be something wrong with the arguments given. I even tried it with ProcessStartInfo. Can't figure this out.

So how should i call the process the same way like over Win+R?

// Edit: Firstgameinformation is the same as If4hH4/27YhyycyAsxthGMnjzXaIgu7F 1249300997

Comment: What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception, i just try to rebuild the exact thing to happen like when i use Win+R and type in this code. As i tried it, it must be different as nothing really happens, but when i use the same code in Win+R it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to set the [ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, so that the new process is started from where it can find for example the LoLLauncher.exe file.